# Table name not recognized in correlated subquery (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM title t1
WHERE t1.rating > 
(SELECT t2.rating FROM title t2 GROUP BY t2.genre 
HAVING t1.genre = t2.genre AND t2.is_movie = 0);
```

Gives me an invalid identifier error. It looks like table t1 is not recognized within the nested subquery. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do, Is it necessary to have `t1.genre = t2.genre`

Comment: The query is supposed to Select all TV shows with a higher rating than the average within their genre. I have to compare the rating of the selected tv show with the average of their genre. To be clear, it's a database comparable to netflix's.

Comment: capture avg in one variable and compare it with your rating.
you can use mysql variables. that may be more helpful.

Comment: Questions:  (1)  if this is Oracle, why the MySQL tag?   (2) Can you please post the EXACT and COMPLETE error message?  Table structure would help too.  (3) if you didn't get this error message yet, you will after you fix other errors... in the subquery, you select t2.rating after you group by t2.genre. This won't fly. If you need the average, then select avg(t2.rating).

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your query this way using inline views on same table joined..

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM title t1,(select genre,avg(rating) as rating
               from title
               where is_movie = 0
               group by genre) t2
WHERE 
     t1.genre = t2.genre
 AND t1.is_movie = 0
 AND t1.rating > t2.rating
```